# Payable to the order of you or Payable to your order

Tags: phrases

Which phrase is correct "Payable to the order of you" or "Payable to your order".

Answer (score 2):

"Payable to the order of ..." is specifically an instruction to the bank.

"Payable to the order of you" is basically a nonsensical instruction.
("Payable to your order" is utterly wrong.)

If you are giving instructions for filing out the instruction "Payable to the order of *your name here*"  might make more sense as an meta-instruction to the filling party.

If you do intend, for some reason, to provide an instruction to the bank to pay itself: "Payable to the order of *Name of Financial Institution*"  If this is not an actual financial document or instruction and a more whimsical reference to same then I would recommend "Payable to the order of yourself!"

Finally, if you are describing an instrument that is going to be "Payable to Order of *The Reader*" it would be described as "made payable to you" as in "you will receive a check made payable to you."

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but *yourself* would also be more idiomatic in the last one.

Comment: I do agree and perhaps it is banking jargon but when I am fortunate enough to receive remittances they never do use the reflexive pronouns as we might expect.

Comment: @TimLymington I think many native speakers would use *yourself* in that last one, but it's not really a reflexive object – it's bank-to-you, not you-to-yourself. So I'd say you're right descriptively but not prescriptively.